# Java thread safety for long stream writer code

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm making an intercom system where the speaker will be transmitting a continuous stream of bytes (audio/video) to multiple sockets depending on how many receivers are registered and which ones of them are being targeted by the user (using a keypad).

For this I manage a list of listener addresses and write to each of them using a transmitter thread , meanwhile the other thread monitors the hardware and network communication to determine if  any addresses should be added to the list or removed from it.

The transmitter thread using a loop that continuously reads the data stream from the input devices and writes it out to the addresses in the list as such its essentially always accessing the list in its lifetime. Using synchronized blocks here might mean acquiring locks almost every cycle ( which I read is extremely expensive) while the list would be sparingly modified.

A race condition is not an issue here since the data being sent is in micro chunks and loss of a few packets is perfectly acceptable.

I currently use an Array list with synchnorization , but I believe there are better ways to do this

```
//this list can be modified by other threads anytime
ArrayList<InetSocketAddress> currentReceivers = new ArrayList<>(); 
.
.

public void run()
{
.
.    
    byte[] toSend = new byte[bufferSize];
    
            DatagramPacket d = new DatagramPacket(toSend,bufferSize);
    
            while(!bTerminating)
            {               
                int actuallyRead = myMicrophoneLine.read(toSend, 0, bufferSize);
    
                d.setData(toSend,0,actuallyRead);
    
                synchronized (currentReceivers) {
    
                    for(InetSocketAddress addr:currentReceivers)
                    {
                        d.setSocketAddress(addr);               
                    
                        try {
                            socket.send(d);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?

Comment: Acquiring a lock is surely not expensive compared to doing any network I/O; this seems like premature optimization.

Comment: The problem is that `socket.send(d);` is in `synchronized` block, so for the time data is being send, you will not be able add new receivers.